# Include file from parent folder

Tags: php, include

I have a PHP file named **check.php** and I'd like to include it inside **connect.php**

**check.php**'s path: `/short/admin/check.php`

**connect.php**'s path: `/short/src/connect.php`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Check.php

```
<?php

include "../src/connect.php";
```

the two dots `..` refer to the parent directory.

#### php.net

[include](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

[require](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)

Comment: I Tried T Use The Two Dots But It's Say Failed To Open Stream

Comment: Sounds link the file doesn't exist at that path.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `../connect.php`

Two dots means parent folder